# How can I use soft delete with relation in node with sequelize

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I Have model user & jobs with relationship.

User table

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    email: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true },
  });

User.associate = function (models) {
    User.hasMany(models.Jobs, { as: 'user_jobs', foreignKey: 'j_users_client_id'})
}
```

JobsTable

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Jobs = sequelize.define('Jobs', {
    j_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    j_users_client_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
 }, {});

  Jobs.associate = function (models) {
    Jobs.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'j_users_client_id', as: 'user_jobs' })
  };
```

I want to delete user using soft delete operation, After if user is deleted then I don't want to get that deleted user jobs from jobs table.

I want to build this functionality by user & jobs table relationship. If this is not possible by relationship between user & job table. then give me suggestion to do this functionality.